# How can I effectively transform the QA team into Agile and scrum?

Tags: agile-testing

I haven't seen any organization solely working on Scrum.

Almost everyone practices Agile, but not completely follow the Scrum or any other process.

Though they practice daily stand up meeting, follow the scrum events while being in Traditional SDLC.

Where and how can I transition the Dev practice that diligently converts and fit in Scrum?

What are the Effective Tools and Framework we can implement in this scenario?

Comment: Do not implement something for the sake of implementing something.

Comment: What are your goals? What are you trying to achieve with this process implementation?

Comment: What are the problems/bottlenecks in the system, you are trying to solve/address with process improvement?

Answer (score 2):

I like the [Modern Testing Principles](https://www.angryweasel.com/ABTesting/modern-testing-principles/), as they great fit and enhance the Agile mindset:

> **Modern Testing Principles**
>
> The Modern Testing Mission Statement: Accelerate the Achievement of Shippable Quality
>
> **The MT Principles**
>
> The seven principles of Modern Testing are:
>
> 1. Our priority is improving the business.
> 2. We accelerate the team and
>      use models like Lean Thinking and the Theory of Constraints to help
>      identify, prioritize and mitigate bottlenecks from the system.
> 3. We are
>      a force for continuous improvement, helping the team adapt and
>      optimize in order to succeed, rather than providing a safety net to
>      catch failures.
> 4. We care deeply about the quality culture of our team,
>      and we coach, lead and nurture the team towards a more mature quality
>      culture.
> 5. We believe that the customer is the only one capable to judge
>      and evaluate the quality of our product
> 6. We use data extensively to
>      deeply understand customer usage and then close the gaps between
>      product hypotheses and business impact.
> 7. We expand testing abilities
>      and knowhow across the team; understanding that this may reduce (or
>      eliminate) the need for a dedicated testing specialist.
>
> From http://moderntesting.org

If every team had someone who lived these principles and guided the other team members to embrace them you would get great [cross-functional team](https://dzone.com/articles/what-it-means-to-be-a-truly-cross-functional-scrum)s, with a high sense of how to build well-tested quality software.

A start is if teams would follow [DoneDone](https://www.jamesshore.com/Agile-Book/done_done.html), making sure features are tested and deployable each iteration, instead of creating [mini-waterfalls](https://agilevelocity.com/scrum/sprint-may-mini-waterfall/) with the risk of just code being finished.

Answer (score 1):

very few places are big enough to have a dedicated QA team that can run its own agile processes. Possibly if you have SDET roles or similar and enterprise test tooling to maintain but very few can afford that. If you can then hire an expert scrum master to get you started because you need advice tailored to your situation.

I have found it far more common to be a QA placed in a scrum team, with the goal of delivering tests with functionality as part of the definition of done.
With a good scrum master, this can be a fun and productive way to be a QA, you are fully engaged and can shift left testing into the design phase.

That is not to say there aren't team activities for a QA team, its good to coordinate efforts across teams and thats a vital part of a good QA process. However, being in two scrum teams tends to undo any of the benefit as it makes for a lot of conflicts and limits the amount of time you can use in one go.

Unless you can clearly say your QA team produces products (frameworks, infrastructure, sdks) then it very likely doesn't need to use agile processes.

Answer (score 1):

Where and how can I transition the Dev practice that diligently converts and fit in Scrum?

- A dedicated Scrum Master will be really helpful for a team from its journey from 
  partially agile team to a fully agile team.
- An Agile coach - This is something helped the most for my team to understand and 
  align better towards agile. An Agile coach can better watch and understand the 
  mistakes the team is doing and also suggest a change in approach to give the team 
  more focus on Agile delivery.
- The entire team attending the agile workshops - I will recommend the whole team attending 
  Interactive agile workshops, where everyone can practice, learn, collaborate and 
  ask questions.
- Read more - last and not the least, read more about agile development and share the 
  interesting articles you read to the whole team. There are a lot of brilliant and helpful articles available online to help transition a team to a high performing agile team.